Using Vega Lite to Display a the first and last percent of date range
I am trying to do a couple of things I want a monotone line of the visits and points that display the percent of patients screened on the first date of the x axis and the last date of the y axis,
I have tried multiple iterations of the code below and ChatGPT and other platforms. THis is the inspiration https://kerrykolosko.com/line-interpolation/  and I have used this a template: Temp vs year.  I am pretty happy with the appearance but I cannot figure out why its a NAN? any insight would be appreciated. Should I use windows or joinaggregate? And if at all possible how can I get it just the first and last percent date.  Thank you AK
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": "container",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "name": "results"
  },
"transform":[
    
    {"filter":"datum.exclusion == '0'"},
  
    {
      "timeUnit":"monthyear",
      "field": "visit_date",
      "as": "visitYear"
    },
{"filter": {"field": "visit_date", 
    "range": [  {"year": 2022, "month": 1},
                {"year": 2023, "month": 12}]
      
    }},
   
    

    { 
        "joinaggregate":[{
          "op":"count",
          "field":"patient_id",
          "as":"TotalPt"

    }], "groupby":[ "race_and_ethnicity", "visitYear"]
    },{
    "joinaggegate": [{
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "TotalPt",
          "as": "SumPt"
        }],
        "groupby": [
          "race_and_ethnicity"
        ]
      } ,
  {
    "calculate": "datum.TotalPt/datum.SumPt",
    "as": "PercentOfTotal"
  },
   {
      "timeUnit":"year",
      "field": "performed_on",
      "as": "MGYear"
    },{
      "timeUnit":"month",
      "field": "performed_on",
      "as": "MGMonth"
    },
    
    {
          "calculate": "datum.MGMonth+' (' +datum.MGYear +')'",
          "as": "CompleteMGDate"
        },
 {"filter": {"field": "performed_on", 
    "range": [  {"year": 2022, "month":1},
                {"year": 2024,"month":12}]
      
    }},   
 {"calculate":"datum.numerator == 1 ?1:0",
     "as":"numerator1"
 } ,{"filter":"datum.numerator!=0"},  
    { "joinaggegate":[{
          "op":"count",
          "field":"numerator1",
          "as":"TotalMG"

    }], "groupby":[ "race_and_ethnicity", "visitYear"]
    },{
    "joinaggregate": [{
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "TotalMG",
          "as": "SumMG"
        }],
        "groupby": [
        "race_and_ethnicity"
        ]
      } ,
  {
    "calculate": "datum.TotalMG/datum.TotalPt",
    "as": "PercentOfMG"},
    {
          "calculate": "format(datum.PercentOfMG, '.0%')",
          "as": "perc_total"
        }
  
],
  "title": "Visits Vs. Percent Screened, Jan2022-CurrentDate",
 
  "encoding": {
    
    "x":{
         "field":"visitYear",
         "type":"ordinal",
         "axis": {"domain":[  {"year": 2022, "month":1},
                {"year": 2024,"month":12}]},
                "title":"Visit Dates Jan2022-2024"
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "field": "numerator",
      "title":"Number of Visits",
      "axis":{"orient":"left"},
      "axis": {"grid": false},
      "scale": {"type": "log"}
      },
    "color": {
      "field": "race_and_ethnicity", "title":"Race"
    },
    "strokeDash": {
      "field": "race_and_ethnicity",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": null
    }
  },
  
  "layer":[
     { 
         
    "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "interpolate":"monotone",
     "opacity": 0.2
  }
    
},
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
         
          "field": "MGYear",
          
                "title":"Visit Dates Jan2022-2024",
          "type": "ordinal"
        
        },
        "y": {
         
            "type": "quantitative"
    ,
          "field": "perc_total",
        
          "title":"% Screened",
                "axis":null
          
        }, "tooltip":[{
      "field":"perc_total","type":"quatitative","title":"Percent Screened:"},{"field":"race_and_ethnicity", "type":"nominal",
          "title":"race_and_ethnicity"
      }
  ]
      },
    "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line","size":3}},
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "bottom",
            "dx": 6,
            "fontWeight": "bold",
            "fontSize":20
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "perc_total"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dx": 6,
            "fontWeight": "normal",
            "fontSize":1,"limit":600
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
             "field": "perc_total"
             
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      }
      ,{
    "encoding": {
      "x": { "field": "MGYear", 
         "timeUnit": "year",
        
                "title":"Visit Dates Jan2022-2024",
          "axis":{"domain": [  {"year": 2022, "month": 1},
                {"year": 2024, "month": 12}]}
      },
      "y": { "field": "perc_total",
        
            "type": "quantitative",
          
          "axis":null
                
      }, "tooltip":[{
      "field":"perc_total","type":"quatitative","title":"Percent Screened:"},{"field":"race_and_ethnicity", "type":"nominal"}
  ],
    
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "bundle",
        "tension": 0,
        "strokeWidth": 3,
          "tooltip": true
      }
    
    },
  
      "layer": [
        {
          
          "mark": {
            "type": "point"
          },"tooltip":{
                   "Title":"Screens by AgeGroup",
                   "field": "perc_total"
                },
          "encoding": {
        
        "x": {
          
          "field": "MGYear",
        
                "title":"Visit Dates Jan2022-2024", "axis":null
          
          
        
        },
            "y": {"field": "perc_total",
                "axis":null
            }, "tooltip":[{
      "field":"perc_total","type":"quatitative","title":"Percent Screened:"},{"field":"race_and_ethnicity", "type":"nominal", "title":"Race and Ethnicity"}
  ]
            }
          }
   
      ]
  }
  
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}

}

Is this for Power BI? We need a working spec with data in the online editor or a .pbix to be able to assist.

I don't have a PBIX file and will try to make up a mock dataset, but I have narrowed down my issue to the calculation TotalMG is notdefined. How do I check that it is valid. I think there may be some nulls in the dataset that are messing up the calculation.
